# modify datetimepicker month / year navigation buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker that I made touch friendly by overriding the OnDropDown event and changing the [style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33500898/4128586) and [size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563851/4128586) of the inner window, as well as [removing the today button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10921472/4128586), it looks good so far except for the navigation buttons.

[image]

Is there a way that I can increase the size of the buttons?
Or add my own?
Or remove them altogether?