# visual studio C# Mysterious change to winform look and feel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have been creating a simple report application using winforms and crystal in Visual Studio 2010.  All was good until one day I opened it up, gave it a run and the entire look and feel changed to the classic windows style. I can't figure out what the heck I did to change this.  I have been looking through every setting and property I can find and have not been able find anything.  In the picture provided, the top window is what it looks like in my designer, and what it looked like before the change.  The bottom picture shows what it looks like now when running.[image: its a freakin picture. what else do you want to know]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made any changes in the System Properties >> Performance Options >> Visual Effects section of your PC settings? That [can override](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764100/does-application-enablevisualstyles-do-anything) `Application.EnableVisualStyles()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you removed this line:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

from your Programs.cs file in the `Main()` method. That's the only way I was able to get that classic look.

Comment: HA!  Thank you!  It was driving me crazy.  I was working on making a splash screen.  Then decided it wasn't necessary so I commented it out.  Looks like I went a little too far.

Comment: @JSON Happens to the best of us haha :)